# SharePoint 2013: CQWP Link slot not grabbing item hyperlink

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, url, links-list

In SP 2010 you simply had to add URL [Custom Columns] in the `Link` slot to have it use that as the hyperlink address for the displayed items.
This no longer appears to be the case.
When I enter that as config for the slot I get the error **"The site or list column group "Custom Columns" does not exist."**

If I just use URL it then links directly to the list item rather than using the hyperlink from the item field.
I tried using Mark Anderson's XSLT as a workaround but that just displays no results whatsoever.